# What's the difference between auto swap and pushing code directly to production?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, swap, production

In Azure App Service you have the option to configure auto swap, which according to the documentation it swaps the slots automatically when you push your code. How is this different from directly pushing your code to production instead of pushing it to the slot that has auto swap enabled? The only advantage I see is that you can manually swap the slots again later if you see something wrong and you want to restore the previous state of the production slot. But that can also be accomplished with `git reset --hard` anyways.

**What are the advantages of using this azure feature instead of just git?**

Comment: On top of that, you can't even use auto swap on Linux and Web App for Containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto Swap gives you a zero downtime deployment, because the stage slot is fully updated and warmed up before the swap takes place.

With a direct push, your app is down while it initializes.